# Realtime RAM access to qemu guest

Tags: qemu

For the purpose of studying, I want to have full access to the physical memory of the guest QEMU in real-time mode. The "pmemsave" command freezes the guest OS. Is there a way for me to somehow map the physical memory to a Linux partition in order to have access in real-time mode?

i try use pmemsave, but it freezes, and i want have realtime access

Answer (score 0):

Wel, this dumps memory in qemu-monitor not creating file on hdd.

`xp /fmt addr`

`xp`
Physical memory dump starting at addr.

`fmt` is a format which tells the command how to format the data.

Its syntax is: `/{count}{format}{size}`

`count`is the number of items to be dumped.

`format`can be x (hex), d (signed decimal), u (unsigned decimal), o (octal), c (char) or i (asm instruction).

`size`
can be b (8 bits), h (16 bits), w (32 bits) or g (64 bits). On x86, h or w can be specified with the i format to respectively select 16 or 32 bit code instruction size.

---

Examples:

Dump 10 instructions at the current instruction pointer:

`(qemu) x/10i $eip`

0x90107063:  ret
0x90107064:  sti
0x90107065:  lea    0x0(%esi,1),%esi
0x90107069:  lea    0x0(%edi,1),%edi
0x90107070:  ret
0x90107071:  jmp    0x90107080
0x90107073:  nop
0x90107074:  nop
0x90107075:  nop
0x90107076:  nop

---

If app is freezing maybe try smaller chunks. This dumps 1 MB...

`pmemsave 0x000 1048576 file.dmp`